# Batch File: Reading XML Removes Exclamation (!) in CDATA on Read

Tags: xml, batch-file, csv

Currently, I have a [script](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/8450004#file-replace-courses-bat) that does the following:

1. Looks in a specific folder
2. Unzips all *.zip files
3. Reads a specific [CSV file](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/8450004#file-courses-csv) that has four columns (oldid,oldname,newid,newname)
4. Finds all *.xml files recursively in the folder ([sample.xml](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/8450004#file-sample-xml))
5. Cycles through *.xml files, creates copy (an original bak & potential modified bak)
6. Replaces oldid,oldname with newid,newname
7. If modified, writes to XML, deleting original file, moving bak to original.

The last step is where my issue is. Currently, when the batch file reads the XML file, it loses the exclamation mark. Before export, sample line is:

`<url><![CDATA[pdf/Post-Rec_Job Model Training.pdf]]></url>`

results to

`<url><[CDATA[pdf/Post-Rec_Job Model Training.pdf]]></url>`

**How can I maintain the exclamation??**

Comment: Don't use delayed expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must ensure delayed expansion is not enabled when you expand a FOR variable that might contain `!` literals. You can modify your :replaceCourseInfo routine to toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop instead of turning it on at the top of the routine.

I agree with foxidrive, I don't see how the modified variable is being used, so I stripped it out.

```
:replaceCourseInfo
    @echo off
    setlocal

    set INTEXTFILE=%~1
    set OUTTEXTFILE=%~1
    copy %INTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%.bak
    copy %INTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%.original.bak
    set BAKFILE=%~1.bak

    if exist "%~1.bak" del /F /Q "%~1.bak"

    REM Walk through XML Lines
    REM @todo Need to prevent losing ! in [!CDATA[
    for /F "delims=" %%U in (%~1) do (
        set LINE=%%U

        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

        if not "!LINE!" == "!LINE:%~2=!" (
            set LINE=!LINE:%~2=%~3!
        )
        >> "%BAKFILE%" echo.!LINE!

        endlocal
    )

    REM If modified, delete original, copy modified bak as new original
    if NOT "%~2"=="%~3" (
        del /F /Q %~1
        copy %BAKFILE% %~1
    )

goto:eof
```

I used to use FOR /F loops to modify text files, but it can often be complex to get the desired result. I wrote the REPL.BAT script that foxidrive speaks of, and now I almost always use REPL.BAT instead of a FOR /F loop to modify files. REPL.BAT is much simpler and faster.

Comment: I added [repl.bat](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/8450004) to my Gists. dbenham would you by any chance have the script using repl.bat as I could not get `type "%~1" | REPL "%~2" "%~3" >> "%BAKFILE%"` from foxidrive to work?

Comment: It needs the `L` literal option to stop characters from being interpretted as regex meta-characters. `REPL "%~2" "%~3" L`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `delayed expansion` - which can be worked around.

You are using the code below - the `modified` variable isn't being used apparently.

You code seems to be simply replacing `%~2` with `%~3` if `%~2` exists in the string and this can be done with `REPL.BAT` by dbenham or `SED` or `VBS search and replace feature`.

```
REM Walk through XML Lines
REM @todo Need to prevent losing ! in [!CDATA[
for /F "delims=" %%U in (%~1) do (
    set LINE=%%U

    if not "!LINE!" == "!LINE:%~2=!" (
        set LINE=!LINE:%~2=%~3!
        set modified=!string:%~2=%~3!

    )
    >> "%BAKFILE%" echo. LINE!
)
```

Here is the `REPL.BAT` workaround to replace the above code:

```
type "%~1" | REPL "%~2" "%~3" L >> "%BAKFILE%"
```

Comment: The REPL.BAT solution needs the `L` literal option: `type "%~1" | REPL "%~2" "%~3" L >> "%BAKEFILE%"`

Comment: @dbenham Thanks Dave.  I had overlooked the Literal option.  Much appreciated.